# Get X_Fowarded_For IP

Tags: proxy, squid

Configuration setup :

192.168.18.130 : Squid3 proxy server on Ubuntu 12.04
192.168.18.131 : WebServer Running
192.168.18.132 : User

I want the use IP to be visible in the PHP page which is running in webserver.

Currently I am not getting X_Forwarded_For

Answer (score 5):

The header is usually hyphens and not underscores. So it is `X-Forwarded-For`. I believe Squid should have this on by default.

The best way to verify that squid is sending this header is to look at at a packet capture with something like [wireshark](http://wireshark.org). Then you can be sure if the issue is with squid or PHP instead of trying to troubleshoot both at once.

Answer (score 3):

Be sure [forwarded_for](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/forwarded_for/) isn't set to anything but "on" (which is default)

Answer (score 0):

**mod_extract_forwarded** apache module will extract x-forwarded-for from HTTP header originated from squid and pass it as normal **REMOTE_ADDR** to the rest of apache/php.

Be sure you have options for x-forwarded-for correctly set in your squid.conf and you are not removing/restricting this HTTP header, by default it is on and "via" header is also added.

I use it in production, effective, good.